# MVC Most efficient way of sharing a datatable between Contoller Action methods & Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, datatable

```
public ActionResult Index(int directoryID)
{
    Someclass sc = new Someclass();
    DataTable dt = sc.method("directory");

    return View(dt);
}

public ActionResult PlotPartial(DataTable dt)
{
    return PartialView(dt);
}
```

The above index method returns a datatable to the IndexView which works fine. In the same View I have a button which should load the PartialView "PlotPartial" passing the entire model which is the datatable. How can I achieve this most efficiently without creating an instance of the datatable twice. Can I share the datatable in both action methods ? I want the entire datatable in the partial view. It does not have any id columns.

Ajax code:

```
$('#btnPlot').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/PlotPartial',
                contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
                data: { dt : @model },
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html'
            })
            .success(function (result) {
                $('#panelB').html(result);
            })
            .error(function (xhr, status) {
                alert(status);
            })
        });
```

In code above line "data: { dt : @model }" does not work.

Can someone help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're passing the entire DataTable back, instead of pulling a fresh version from the DB, there's really no reason to use ajax for this at all.

In your view, go ahead and render the PlotPartial view as well.

```
<div id='OriginalContent' class='ReplacableContent'>
    // Put the initial content here
</div>
<div id='PlotPartial1' style='display:none' class='ReplacableContent'>
    @Html.Partial("PlotPartial1", Model)
</div>
<div id='PlotPartial2' style='display:none' class='ReplacableContent'>
    @Html.Partial("PlotPartial2", Model)
</div>
<div id='PlotPartial3' style='display:none' class='ReplacableContent'>
    @Html.Partial("PlotPartial3", Model)
</div>
<div id='PlotPartial4' style='display:none' class='ReplacableContent'>
    @Html.Partial("PlotPartial4", Model)
</div>
<div id='Controls'>
    //Put your buttons here
</div>
```

Each button should do something like this:

```
$(".ReplacableContent").hide(); // Hide everything else
$("PlotPartial1").show(); // Show the indicated partial
```

(Updated to address request in comment.)

Comment: Dave thanks for your help. the only problem with the above is I want to replace the container/div with my partial view i.e. replace the entire html. And there will be 4 different containers/partial views which I will call using my four buttons which should replace the same div body. can you pls help with some code. thanks

Comment: That should get you started.  Again, the basic idea is, since it's all the same data anyway, render it all to begin with.  Then simply hide/show the appropriate pieces.